# sap.m.List is not reacting to events

Tags: sapui5

I have the following list, but it is not reacting to any of the events that I'm using. 
In the method onSelectionChange i have breakpoints and is updating the label, but it is for some reason not reaching this. The onSearch method is working fine. 
I'm using the sapui5

```
<mvc:View
height="100%"
controllerName="Tasks.CompletedTasks.view.CompletedTasks"
xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
xmlns="sap.m">

        <SearchField
                liveChange="onSearch"
                width="100%" />
     <Label  id="label" text="test">

     </Label>
      <List
            id="idList"
            items="{/results}"
            select="onSelectionChange"
             >

            <items>
                <StandardListItem
                    title="{TaskTitle}"
                    description="{InstanceID}"
                icon="sap-icon://task"
                    iconDensityAware="false"
                    iconInset="false"
                    />
            </items>
        </List>
```

Code:

```
jQuery.sap.require("jquery.sap.resources");
jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.model.Filter");
jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.model.FilterOperator");
jQuery.sap.require("Tasks.CompletedTasks.util.ModelBuilder");
sap.ui.controller("Tasks.CompletedTasks.view.CompletedTasks", {

/**
* Called when a controller is instantiated and its View controls (if available) are already created.
* Can be used to modify the View before it is displayed, to bind event handlers and do other one-time initialization.
* @memberOf cscompletedtasks.CompletedTasks
*/
    onInit: function() {
    //this.getView().bindElement("/results");
    },

    onSelectionChange : function (oEvt) {

        var oList = oEvt.getSource();
        var oLabel = this.getView().byId("label");

        oLabel.setText("event");

    },
    onSearch : function (oEvt) {

        // add filter for search
        var aFilters = [];
        var sQuery = oEvt.getSource().getValue();
        if (sQuery && sQuery.length > 0) {
            var filter = new sap.ui.model.Filter("TaskTitle", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, sQuery);
            aFilters.push(filter);
        }

        // update list binding
        var list = this.getView().byId("idList");
        var binding = list.getBinding("items");
        binding.filter(aFilters, "Application");
    }



});
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=UTF-8' />

<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
    src="https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
    data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
    data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
    data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"
    data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{"Tasks.CompletedTasks" : "./" }'>

</script>

<script>
    new sap.ui.core.ComponentContainer( {
        name : "Tasks.CompletedTasks"
    }).placeAt("content");
</script>

</head>
<body class="sapUiBody" id="content">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The **select** event work if you set the **mode** of selection on the **list**.

```
<List
            id="idList"
            items="{/results}"
            select="onSelectionChange",
            mode="" //Type of mode you required SingleSelect,MultiSelect, Delete default it is None.
             >

            <items>
                <StandardListItem
                    title="{TaskTitle}"
                    description="{InstanceID}"
                icon="sap-icon://task"
                    iconDensityAware="false"
                    iconInset="false"
                    />
            </items>
        </List>
```

refer this [link](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.ListBase.html#getMode) for more information

Comment: I have added mode = SingleSelect, but it is not changing any things. The list is showed differently but it is not reacting to the event.

Comment: there must be a radio button is added in the list press that radio button the function will get triggered.

Comment: There is a radio button, but it is still not reacting to inputs.

Comment: Select the radio button, onSelectionChange function will trigger set a breakpoint in the function and check.

Comment: I have added the logging and it shows that it is activating other events but not the events from the select ty

Comment: You have registered some other events, such as itemPress,  press, or tap  of List and ListItem

Comment: I have tried also using itemPress, press and tap but wihtout making any change.

Answer (score 0):

Please slot this at the top of the function handling the onSelectionChange event:

jQuery.sap.log.setLevel(jQuery.sap.log.LogLevel['INFO']);
jQuery.sap.log.info("*** my onSelectionChange has triggered");

i.e.:

```
onSelectionChange : function (oEvt) {

   jQuery.sap.log.setLevel(jQuery.sap.log.LogLevel['INFO']); 
   jQuery.sap.log.info("*** my onSelectionChange has triggered");
   var oList = oEvt.getSource();
```

Then check the console of your browser and filter to find the output of this message. (Just in case the event is triggering and your consequent code doesn't do anything. (if you have set the LogLevel elsewhere please ignore)